# How can i add data automatically

Tags: mysql

```
    CREATE TABLE `tmp` (
    `CallID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `InfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `CallStartTime` datetime NOT NULL,
    KEY `CallStartTime` (`CallStartTime`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

in this table i want to add one more column `PartitionID` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 here i want insert data of PartitionID column, that means PartitionID=(DAYOFYEAR('2009-01-01 00:00:00')) = 1 
 i want insert data automatically ... 
PartitionID=(DAYOFYEAR(`CallStartTime`))

my table old data like this

```
        (144,   56, '2011-06-19 1:00:00'),
        (100,   57, '2011-09-01 10:24:00'),
        (168,   68, '2012-07-13 12:10:06'),
        (207,   30,         '12012-12-05 12:12:00'),
        (112,   14, '2013-05-19 1:00:00');
        (177,   90, '2013-06-05 12:12:00'),
        (144,   56, '2013-06-19 1:00:00'),
        (168,   68,     '2013-07-13 12:10:06'),
        (119,   17, '2013-08-01 10:24:00'),
        (110,   10, '2013-08-05 12:12:00'),
        (113,   11, '2013-08-13 12:10:06'),
        (100,   57, '2013-09-01 10:24:00'),
```

after adding new column ...i want like this

only insert `PartitionID`  data automatically not manually

```
(177,   90, '2010-06-05 12:12:00',156),
(144,   56, '2011-06-19 01:00:00',170),
(100,   57, '2011-09-01 10:24:00',244),
(168,   68, '2012-07-13 12:10:06',194),
(207, 30, '2012-12-05 12:12:00',340),
(112,   14, '2013-05-19 01:00:00',139),
(177,   90, '2013-06-05 12:12:00',156),
(144,   56, '2013-06-19 01:00:00',170),
(168,   68, '2013-07-13 12:10:06',194),
(119,   17, '2013-08-01 10:24:00',213),
(110,   10, '2013-08-05 12:12:00',217),
(113,   11, '2013-08-13 12:10:06',225),
(100,   57, '2013-09-01 10:24:00',244)
```

Comment: Use ALTER TABLE 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: It would  be nice if you tried to format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value for that column since it is a calculated value and defaults need to be constants. But you can create a trigger that calculates that value on insert

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER PartitionIDtrigger BEFORE INSERT ON tmp
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.PartitionID = DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE());
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: You can update existing records with a simple update statement: `update tmp set PartitionID = DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: suppose ihave data start 2009-01-01 to today ... then how can i update all rows

Comment: when iam excecute this trigger it will gives error:
Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: @karukala.sr: Then change the trigger to `before` as I just did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD NewCol int
CONSTRAINT DF_TestTable_NewCol DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL
GO
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is used to add a new column with default value one.

You can then create a TRIGGER as @juergen d said and then change the values.

Comment: i dont want default value...... i want update PartitionID row with DAYOFYEAR(CallStartTime) values

Comment: @karukala You can use juergens' answer after this step and update it.